# compare text from text field with lookup field

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, lookup-column

I would like to extract keywords from a document title in a SP List. I have three columns. The first is a text column containing the document Title. The second is a lookup column containing some keywords. The third is a multiline column which will hold the keywords found in the Title column.

For example:
(Lookup) column keywords: apples, oranges, strawberry, banana

Title: 20210312_we have apples and oranges for sale today.doc

The code I am looking for would have to extract the words "apples" and "oranges" found in the document title and place them in the column keywords, seperated by a semi-column

Comment: What kind of "code" are you looking for?  How do you want this process to happen? Via a workflow? Something on the client side (Javascript)?  What would trigger it? Using an event receiver / server-side C# code?

Comment: @DylanCristy I was thinking about javascript on the client side, validation of the column if that is possible